# Typescript assign null to interface

Tags: typescript, interface

This might be a silly question, but I can't figure out how to set a value of `null` to variable declared to be of an interface type.

Below is an example of what I mean:

```
interface IMyInterface {
    field: any;
}

let test:IMyInterface = null; // <-- Compiler error: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'IMyInterface'
```

Comment: `let test:IMyInterface | null = null;`

Comment: And what if that interface is and argument of a function I can't change? Specifically I'm trying to pass null to the default value of react `createContext`

Comment: You would get solutions to the real issue much quicker if you posted a question that has your actual code and problem description instead of a question that's [too abstract to solve the actual issue](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: You are absolutely right. My apologies, I thought the issue I had was related to soming I was missing with the declaration of my interface.

Answer (score 9):

Either define it to be an union type, or set the `strictNullChecks` flag to false in your ts-config under `compilerOptions`.

by @Guy Incognito:

```
let test:IMyInterface | null = null;
```

Answer (score 6):

Enabling the [compiler setting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) `strictNullChecks` (which is also included in the `strict` setting) removes `null` and `undefined` from each type and thus requires these to be explicitly declared. [TypeScript handbook on Nullable types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#nullable-types).

Without `strictNullChecks`:

```
declare let implicitlyNullable: number;

implicitlyNullable = 42;        //OK
implicitlyNullable = null;      //OK
implicitlyNullable = undefined; //OK
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?strictNullChecks=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=37#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd4EsC2AHCaxuQgE8A5AVwmgCMkAueAOzIypBgG4BYAKB8xzwFi5SlBoIAvPAAsAJnbxFSxQHoVAeQDSfbLnyFSFaknhSmlBcvhqtOgfuFGxJqWQagAZmgYhgCm5pAA)

With `strictNullChecks`:

```
declare let implicitlyNullable: number;

implicitlyNullable = 42;        //OK
implicitlyNullable = null;      //error
implicitlyNullable = undefined; //error

///////////////////////////////////////

declare let explicitlyNullable: number | null;

explicitlyNullable = 42;        //OK
explicitlyNullable = null;      //OK
explicitlyNullable = undefined; //error

///////////////////////////////////////

declare let explicitlyUndefinable: number | undefined;

explicitlyUndefinable = 42;        //OK
explicitlyUndefinable = null;      //error
explicitlyUndefinable = undefined; //OK

///////////////////////////////////////

//nilable = can be both undefined and null
declare let explicitlyNilable: number | undefined | null;

explicitlyNilable = 42;        //OK
explicitlyNilable = null;      //OK
explicitlyNilable = undefined; //OK
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=36#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd4EsC2AHCaxuQgE8A5AVwmgCMkAueAOzIypBgG4BYAKB8xzwFi5SlBoIAvPAAsAJnbxFSxQHoVAeQDSfbLnyFSFaknhSmlBcvhq2MAPYwdA-cKNiTUsg1AAzNAxBgBRsYe0debjUo6JjYuPjonh5QSFgEJFQQAA9nIUNRcXomFjZ4AB9GIy4I7NyDEWNJGXkrJTUtHlq9PIb3JvMIS2V27W4uwXq3cVN4L19-QOCVWwckyISNzfi1lOg4RBR4cZciAFVvED8GPqLmVhhy2YurxbXjvPP56+mpOSGrEadHLdAyfS7+PozAb-VTLUKrMbAibEMFXSGeZ4LILWDSjHhbAmEtZqBhoRozMBQBjwVg0uzIAAWTy+gXgVOAlUoyXAe3Sh3e9TJN0qJQeFTm4ICHIq0LeSJOJCFP2aMLauKBdWESo8nMGrUBiM1pG1TQlL2xIyAA)

---

In essence, the compiler option is very similar to automatically applying the [`NonNullable` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullablet) to every type in existence. So, without `strictNullChecks` being you don't accept "empty" values is an opt-*in*.

Speaking for myself, I much prefer the exactness of `strictNullChecks`. It makes it much easier to write and reason about code without having to sprinkle `if(someVar)` everywhere because you don't know what somebody would pass in. Even a simple function can be a problem without strict null checks:

```
function add(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b;
}

console.log(add(2, 3));         //strictNullChecks: false -> 5
                                //strictNullChecks: true  -> 5
console.log(add(2, null));      //strictNullChecks: false -> 2
                                //strictNullChecks: true  -> compiler error
console.log(add(2, undefined)); //strictNullChecks: false -> NaN
                                //strictNullChecks: true  -> compiler error
```

[Playground Link - `strictNullChecks: false`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?strictNullChecks=false#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQEMAmmAU6BcqUEAtgEYCmATgDSpmHHnUCUjplVqA3qKv6ioU4EKmnSoA1PQDcoAL6hQMFAGckAGwoA6DUgDmebDgBMdAMwsWMgbf4B6e6gC0APlQBWZWs069hrFwzIggNDSsbO0cXdxNvKHUtXQMjILpoTAowBCgKTAjUaLdUADl0EqA)

[Playground Link - `strictNullChecks: true`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoBTIFyLCAWwCMBTAJwBpEjd9jyBKWw0sxAbwFgAoRPxMiSggySZIgDU1ANw8Avjx4QEAZzgAbEgDp1cAOZZ0GAExUAzAwbT+NvgHo7iALQA+RAFYlqjdt0G0mKZ4IOrqlta2Ds5uygQADjCabORkcGReYGqaOvqGgVTgqCTAMGAkqOGIUa6IsQlJiEA)

---

For convenience, you can create some generic types that handle different types of nullability:

```
type Nullable<T> = T | null;
type Undefinable<T> = T | undefined;
type Nilable<T> = Nullable<Undefinable<T>>

declare let implicitlyNullable: number;
declare let explicitlyNullable: Nullable<number>;
declare let explicitlyUndefinable: Undefinable<number>;
declare let explicitlyNilable: Nilable<number>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgGwQQwEYIgHgCoD4oC8U2UAPlAHaIIDcAsAFCiRQCqFAJhAGYCWFaDDnxES5OJx78IHek3DQYvFOix5CsaoKzsufAauG5GjLgGMUAJ2gZgUXgFswCXmd7AEIeEm0AuSnAOqBCWcoyOzq7unt4qGBoALABMNFBp6WkA9JkA8gDS4U4ubh5eWqoaVEipGVDZIZYA9paFkSUx5fFEEnrSsnWZDc0mDNlj4xOTU9PjI+ZWNhB2EAAebdFlPqr+sdqYVEEhuGEMq+uluxVEyTW1A-mMZ8Ubl10B1XfZD6drzxed0G6kn0MlS9UsTRaDEYM1hcJmcwgFmQ1igtigTyipV0UgMGH8OP0ewOwUsxxGmPaIEJ-G0iRSdyyuQKP3OnhpeMB71on0GEOGrL+7OBtKuUB6uNB9xZMPhcrlI2yFGUdKIZmQFCgwS1jWAAAtxSKKDIoBqONzTEiFmilhjfliYirtrAnUISUcTpSXq6uTdGdLHvaqUo4lyqjzal8WV6Lj6NBKQf0o0A)

Answer (score 1):

```
let test:IMyInterface = null as unknown as IMyInterface;
```